# Press event or navigation from card control in sapui5

Tags: sapui5

I am using cards to display some data. i want to call some function on click of card control in sapui5.

```
<f:Card class="sapUiMediumMargin carousalCards" width="360px">
    <f:content>
        <VBox height="370px" justifyContent="SpaceBetween">
            <HBox justifyContent="SpaceBetween">
                <VBox>
                    <Title class="titleWidth" text="{getfileDefaultJSONModel>REFERENCE}" level="H1"/>
                    <Text class="sapMGTSubHdrTxt" text="{getfileDefaultJSONModel>CREATION_DATE}"></Text>
                </VBox>
                <HBox class="checkedIcon">
                    <RadioButton custom:model="getfileDefaultJSONModel" select="fnCreateClone" text="{getfileDefaultJSONModel>ID}" groupName="GroupA" visible="{getfileDefaultJSONModel>RADIO_VISIBLE}"/>
                </HBox>
            </HBox>
            <HBox justifyContent="SpaceBetween" class="largeTileFooter">
                <Text class="sapMTileCntFtrTxt" text="{getfileDefaultJSONModel>USER_ID} {getfileDefaultJSONModel>REFERENCE} Data"></Text>
                <Text class="sapMNCValue Neutral" text="{getfileDefaultJSONModel>JSON_SIZE}"></Text>
            </HBox>
        </VBox>
    </f:content>
</f:Card>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `sap.f.Card` does not have any `click` event. You can, however, use the browser events:

```
var card = this.getView().byId("your-card-id");
card.attachBrowserEvent("click", function(event) {
    // handle card click
}, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing, `sap.f.Card` does **not** provide any press events. You could..

- Stick with the guidelines and make only the header clickable. Controls that implement `sap.f.cards.IHeader` do provide `press` event.
- Or leverage `sap.m.CustomListItem` with `type="Active"` to make the card content clickable.

See the demo below:

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/Fragment",
], Fragment => Fragment.load({
  definition: `<f:Card xmlns:f="sap.f" width="18rem" class="sapUiSmallMargin">
    <f:header>
      <cards:Header xmlns:cards="sap.f.cards"
        title="Clickable Header"
        statusText="Status"
        press="alert('Header pressed')"
      />
    </f:header>
    <f:content>
      <FlexBox xmlns="sap.m" renderType="Bare" width="100%">
        <CustomListItem type="Active" press="alert('Card pressed')">
          <HBox height="7rem" justifyContent="SpaceAround" alignItems="Center">
            <Title text="Clickable Card" titleStyle="H4" />
            <core:Icon xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
              src="sap-icon://sap-ui5"
              size="4rem"
              color="#ff7b17"
              class="sapUiTinyMarginBottom"
            />
          </HBox>
          <layoutData>
            <FlexItemData minWidth="100%" />
          </layoutData>
        </CustomListItem>
      </FlexBox>
    </f:content>
  </f:Card>`,
}).then(control => control.placeAt("content"))));
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://ui5.sap.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core, sap.m, sap.f, sap.ui.layout"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitForTheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```